# How is image set of a filterbase a filterbase?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Given $f\colon X\to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and $B$ a filterbase in $X$, how do you show that $f(B)=\{f(b)|b \in B\}$ is a filterbase in $Y$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You simply verify that it satisfies the definition. Let $\mathscr{A}=\{f[B]:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$, where $\mathscr{B}$ is a filter base in $X$; you must show

1. that $\varnothing\notin\mathscr{A}$, and
2. that for any $A_0,A_1\in\mathscr{A}$ there is an $A\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $A\subseteq A_0\cap A_1$.

I’ll leave (1) completely to you. For (2), suppose that $A_0,A_1\in\mathscr{A}$; then there are $B_0,B_1\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $A_0=f[B_0]$ and $A_1=f[B_1]$. Since $\mathscr{B}$ is a filter base on $X$, there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $B\subseteq B_0\cap B_1$. Now what should the desired $A$ be?

Comment: Ah. $A = f[B]$ does it. I feel so stupid now. Thank you so much :).

Comment: @Fatsho: You’re welcome. (It happens to all of us.)